# Populate a Chart from firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, charts

I've been stuck all day, I'm trying to implement a chart on my app that has to collect some data from my firebase database to use them to populate the chart.
I've try this code to get the data from the database:

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let bslChecksDB = Database.database().reference().child("BSL Checks").child(userID!)
        bslChecksDB.observe((.childAdded)) { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String : [String: String]]
            print(snapshotValue)
            self.arrayOfDic = Array(snapshotValue.values)

        for i in 0...self.arrayOfDic.count - 1 {
            self.snapshotDictionary = self.arrayOfDic[i]
            let date = self.snapshotDictionary["Date"]!
            let time = self.snapshotDictionary["Time"]!
            let bsl = Double(self.snapshotDictionary["BSL"]!)
            let unit = self.snapshotDictionary["Unit"]!
            let dateTime = "\(date) at: \(time)"

            self.dateTimeArray.append(dateTime)
            self.bslDataArray.append(bsl!)
            self.uuuuDataArray.append(unit)

        }
```

I try to print the various arrays to see if they were made and they were, so no problem (i thought). then when I proceed to upload those data on the chart, they disappear.... It seems like my arrays are wiped out as soon as they are made! What is wrong?

```
for i in 0...self.dateTimeArray.count - 1 {
                ChartFormatter().array.append(self.dateTimeArray[i])

        }
        print("array")
        print(ChartFormatter().array)

    }

    var lineChartEntry = [ChartDataEntry] ()

    print(dateTimeArray.count)
    for i in 0...dateTimeArray.count - 1 {
        let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: bslDataArray[i])
        lineChartEntry.append(value)
    }


    let line1 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry, label: "BSL")
    line1.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
    let data = LineChartData ()
    data.addDataSet(line1)
    chtChart.data = data
    chtChart.chartDescription?.text = "My graph"
```

Since this is the first time I implement a chart on my app, could you please explain how to populate the chart with data from a firebase database? thanks